# Redis Lexicographicset Timeout error When Using lex.Match Instead of lex.Autocomplete

Tags: c#, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis, cachingframework.redis

I'm using an Azure redis cache to hold some data, and using an IRedisLexicographicSet to read that data in an "autocomplete" type of function. The below code works fine:

```
var context = new CachingFramework.Redis.RedisContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CacheConnection"].ToString());
CachingFramework.Redis.Contracts.RedisObjects.IRedisLexicographicSet lex = context.Collections.GetRedisLexicographicSet("autocomplete");
IEnumerable<string> suggestions = lex.AutoComplete(enteredText.ToUpper());
```

The problem is that the "AutoComplete" only takes the wildcard at the right (string*), and I need left & right (*string*).

From what I've read, I want to use the "Match" function, but when I change my code to

```
var context = new CachingFramework.Redis.RedisContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CacheConnection"].ToString());
CachingFramework.Redis.Contracts.RedisObjects.IRedisLexicographicSet lex = context.Collections.GetRedisLexicographicSet("autocomplete");
IEnumerable<string> suggestions = lex.Match("*" + enteredText.ToUpper() + "*");
```

I get the error:

Timeout performing ZSCAN autocomplete, inst: 0, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 1, qu: 1, qs: 0, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 1, in: 0, ar: 0, clientName: D100169, serverEndpoint: Unspecified/taxweb.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, keyHashSlot: 16074, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=3,Free=8188,Min=8,Max=8191) (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

The execution time is pretty much immediate, it's not timing out in the sense that it's taking too long.

I've read the link in the error message and am still not sure what the solution is. I've tried adding  "syncTimeout=600000" to the connection string and that did not solve it either.

Little help?
Thanks.

Comment: I've tried using conn.PreserveAsyncOrder = false; and I've tried making the connection async as well. This is very frustrating!

Comment: Are you creating a new `RedisContext` for each call? you should [reuse a shared reference](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis#the-rediscontext-object-should-be-shared-and-reused-between-callers-it-is-not-recommended-to-create-a-rediscontext-per-operation-please-check-stackexchangeredis-documentation-for-more-information).

Comment: I was creating a new instance for each call yes, but changing it to a shared RedisContext did not help with error....

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this. Can you share more about your context? how many items does the set have? Does it fail the first time/always? what's the size of your set members? Does it fails connecting to a local redis server?

Comment: The set is a little over 85 000 records. It fails immediately, first time, every time, unless I add a .ToList() to end of the call, at which point it hangs for a very long time. The members are strings, about 40-50 characters. The cache is not local, it is an Azure Redis cache

Comment: On the new library version (10.0.4), you could try with different values for the [**Scan Page Size (Count)**](https://redis.io/commands/scan#the-count-option) for the Match operation on your LexSet instance, for example: `context.Collections.GetRedisLexicographicSet("autocomplete", 100)`